# Chrome extension calls to executeScript stop working after downloading a file in a page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

An extension I'm working on behaves strangely after the user follows a link that downloads a file.

If I run the following bit of code from a context menu the alert is displayed as expected, and I can call it any number of times and it will work :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "alert('hello')", allFrames: true }, 
    function () { 
        console.log("alert completed"); 
    });
```

As soon download a file from that same page, execute script stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use the passed to function `tabid` variable instead of `null`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug to me. You should open an issue on [crbug.com](http://new.crbug.com).

Comment: If anybody has this issue, please feel free to add details to the bug report [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104853)